# Oracle select query multiple tables

Tags: oracle

I need to write a query to show Emp Id, Task Id, Task Name, Start Date, End Date for all tasks from these two tables

TASK

```
taskid      (primary key)
taskname
givendate
startdate
enddate
maxhours
```

JOB

```
taskid      (primary key, foriegn key)
empid       (primary key, foriegn key)
hoursspent
```

My query is `SELECT empid, taskid, taskname, startdate, enddate FROM task, job WHERE task.taskid=job.taskid`

I keep getting

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use explizit join:

```
SELECT empid, task.taskid, taskname, startdate, enddate FROM task Join job on task.taskid=job.taskid
```

And aliases for columns that names are not unique